# Tipler and omega point spacetimes

Tags: event-horizon, singularities

The physicist Frank Tipler has argued that spacetimes which end in a single point at what is called an "Omega Point" could have no event horizons. In which case, what would stop us seeing naked singularities? He claims our universe can end up in such a point?

Comment: Hi Dominique, welcome to PSE! Can you please include a reference for Tipler's claim. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tipler focuses on spacetimes that are collapsing in a particular way (it is a [Bianchi IX mixmaster collapse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bianchi_classification#Cosmological_application)); at the end they end up as a single point. But this is the future timelike boundary: there are no places outside that point, so no observer will see a naked singularity until they end up in it. This is not too different from the collapse of the simplest FLRW models.

The whole point of avoiding horizons is that Tipler wants every observer to be able to send messages to every other observer an infinite number of times, not to hide singularities.

Comment: Most of this I can follow but not quite sure why observers looking at a black hole right now cannot see the naked singularity of a black hole.

Comment: @Dominique - you cannot see it because (1) there is a horizon there (so it is not naked), and (2) inside a normal black hole the singularity is time-like rather than space-like. That means that for observers inside the black hole it is ahead of them in (their) time, it is not like it is sitting there at a particular spot. You need to change the standard black hole spacetime to something else to get a naked singularity.

Comment: Yes will need to think on this but if horizons are to be avoided why would an horizon be present to stop me seeing the singularity? Thank you Anders for your patience with me.

Comment: Note that Tipler is trying to do something special to get his Omega Point. Most physicists think singularities are cloaked by horizons (cosmic censorship, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_censorship_hypothesis ), but there are also horizons that just block communication like the cosmological event horizon with no singularities on the other side.